# Are Shinra Shakaki's Parents Ever Revealed?

Tags: c.m.b

I have read the English Translated version of C.M.B. Manga and there was no mention of Shinra's biological father. Only his adoptive fathers and mother were mentioned.

As the manga is finished. Is it ever revealed?